# Angularjs-nvd3-directives for line chart - BOLD

Tags: angularjs

I am using a Angularjs nvd3-line-chart and I would like to make the trend lines **bold** there are 2 trend lines on each graph and there are multiple small graphs displayed on one page so the standard line is hard to see. I'm not sure if Angularjs-nvd3-directives supports this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have tried looking on the internet to see the directive to change it to bold and found nothing, also I added bold="true" which makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

`<b>` tag makes bold style to fonts maybe you can use a combination with `<b>` and `<span>` making use of default angular directives. If you need something more complex you can also implement your own angularJS directives to achieve what you want. Take a look here http://henriquat.re/directives/introduction-to-directives/introductionToDirectives.html